# Is it expected that I can call a function with a receiver object by passing the receiver object in as the first argument?

Tags: kotlin

Using the example in Kotlin's document on Function Literals with Receiver:

```
val sum = fun Int.(other: Int): Int = this + other
```

The sum function can be invoked like this as if it were a method of the receiver object:

```
1.sum(2)
```

However I noticed that we can also invoke the function like this:

```
sum(1, 2)
```

Of course both of them give the same results. My question is if the behavior is expected? Or did I miss something in the documentation?

Comment: are your later usage in kotlin? If it's in java then it's intended, as nhaarman has suggested below. If it's in kotlin then I think we got a bug here. I don't see why jetbrains would add such a functionality.

Comment: The latter one was also in Kotlin.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, extension functions are compiled as static functions with the receiver as the first parameter. So for example:

```
 fun Int.sum(other: Int): Int = this + other
```

somewhat compiles to:

```
 static int sum(int receiver, int other) {
   return receiver + other;
 }
```